# The loop prints the smallest number as the largest

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the smallest and largest numbers, but the output of the program is incorrect. The smallest is the largest in the output and the largest is always 1 smaller than the largest. I entered 2, 4, 6, 8, heres the output:

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: done
('largest is', 7)
('smallest is', 8)
```

And here's the code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:

    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        halo = int(num)
    except:
        print("invalid input")
        continue
    for largest in range(halo):
        if largest is None:
            largest = halo
        elif largest > halo:
            largest = halo
    for smallest in range(halo):
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = halo
        elif smallest<halo:
            smallest = halo
print "largest is",largest
print "smallest is",smallest
```

Comment: Use `min` and  `max` on a `list` you collect the entered integers in.

Comment: `largest in range()` assigns every value in your range to that variable. It'll either be the highest count from your range or the last `halo` value entered.

Comment: Because `largest` is your `for` loop variable, `if largest is None` is **never** going to be true. Because you run over `range(halo)`, `largest > halo` is never going to be true either, so in the end `largest` will be the last `halo` minus 1. Always.

Comment: @LutzHorn: well, they don't *have* a list, they are comparing numbers as they are entered. Using comparisons in a loop can work, provided you don't make matters too complicated like the OP did here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True. Using a list would save him from implementing min/max logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always assigning a value to `largest` and `smallest` because you use them as targets in a `for` loop:

```
for largest in range(halo):
```

In the above, `largest` will be assigned `0`, then `1`, then `2` all the way up to the last number for `halo`.

Next, you have your `<` and `>` comparisons the wrong way around; you are only updating `largest` if `halo` is *smaller*. Invert your tests.

You don't need any loops at all here, your `while True` loop is your looping construct. Just test `halo` directly against `largest` and `smallest`:

```
try:
    halo = int(num)
except:
    print("invalid input")
    continue
if largest is None or halo > largest:
    largest = halo
if smallest is None or halo < smallest:
    smallest = halo
```